# Using Swift in Xcode I want to import glibc

Tags: swift3, glibc, xcode8

On macOS, using Xcode, I want to test some code with

```
import Glibc
```

instead of

```
import Darwin
```

Has anyone made this work?

The question is not about how to use #if to choose which to import based on the platform. Clearly glibc has been ported to macOS. I'm looking for how to set up the environment so I can import Glibc on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe taking a look at Cgd might reveal a solution?

https://github.com/twostraws/Cgd/blob/master/module.modulemap

You might be able to similarly define a MacGlibc module which exposes a Mac-specific glibc at a location of your choice.